# How to show a local agenda or local notification by hour and day

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have this array it's already populated in a table view with dynamic cells, what I want it's create a local agenda or notification or alarm or something similar to remind the user to take the medicine at the day and the hour that is displayed in the array, could you help me? please. Thanks a lot.

```
{“medicine”:”paracetamol”

        “day”:”tuesday”

        “time”:”9:00”},

         {“medicine”:”aspirine”

        “day”:”friday”

        “time”:”16:00”},

         {“medicine”:”pills”

        “day”:”monday”

        “time”:”22:00”}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a calendar object and set your weekday and time values in comps.weekday, comps.hour and comps.minute properties.

And for your message, set in notification content.body property.

```
import UserNotifications

let calendar = NSCalendar.init(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
calendar?.locale = NSLocale.current

let year = calendar?.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar?.component(.month, from: date)

let cal = Calendar.current
var comps = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: date)
comps.weekday = i // Monday - Friday
comps.hour = j
comps.minute = minute
comps.year = year
comps.month = month

let notificationDate = cal.date(from: comps)!
let interval = String.init(format: "%d%d%d", i,j,minute)


if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

    let triggerDate =  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: notificationDate as Date)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = DataManager.sharedInstance.notificationTitle
    content.body = String.init(format: "%@", DataManager.sharedInstance.notificationMessage)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: String(interval), content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

} else {
    // ios 9


    // Fallback on earlier versions
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    /* Time and timezone settings */
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.weekday
    notification.timeZone = NSCalendar.current.timeZone
    notification.alertBody = "message"

    notification.userInfo = [ "title" : String(interval)]

    /* Schedule the notification */
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

1. Convert your json to NSArray of NSDictionary objects. using NSJSonSerialisation class.
2. Run a for loop with the NSArray instance and access NSDictionary objects one by one.
3. Use NSDictionary valueForKey method. Pass the key name and get the value from dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this, but i don't know how to access to the key "time" and "hour" and assing it to the comps.hour and comps.weekday :(

Comment: @user8172235 updated my answer with steps to access data from json. cheers :)